# Array of objects with different schemas - JOI

Tags: javascript, hapi.js, joi

I currently have the following schema on my app:

```
Joi.object().keys({
  users: Joi.array().items(mySchema)
})
```

So I can get an array of users and validate them. 
But now I need different schemas for each object.

Is there a way I can do something like:

```
Joi.object().keys({
  users: [
    Joi.object().keys(mySchemaForUserOne),
    Joi.object().keys(mySchemaForUserTwo),
    // ...
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go ~

```
Joi.object().keys({
  users: Joi.array().items(
    Joi.alternatives()
      .conditional('.type', {
        switch: [{
          is: 'mySchemaForUserOne',
          then: Joi.object({ ... }),
        }, {
          is: 'mySchemaForUserTwo',
          then: Joi.object({ ... }),
        }],
      })
  )
})
```

You can check documents here =>
[Joi conditional API](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.2.1#alternativesconditionalcondition-options)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array.items` by listing all allowed types. If a given type is `.required()` then there must be a matching item in the array: [joi API reference](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.1.2/API.md#arrayitemstype)

```
users: Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys(mySchemaForUserOne).required(),
                         Joi.object().keys(mySchemaForUserTwo).required(),
                         // ...)
```

Comment: Not sure why but that does not work as expected. I am sending [userOne, userTwo] to be validated against this schema, and they are all validated by the first option, which is `Joi.object().keys(mySchemaForUserOne).required()`

Comment: @Metarat have you found any solution? I am also looking for the same thing but no luck yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74658952/joi-validations-if-object-matches-the-schema-validate-against-it-from-multiple